# COUNTIF function shows a date instead of a number as a result

Tags: excel, vba, formula, countif

I was creating a frequency worksheet for the new classes i'll be taking this semester, but when i try to use the `COUNTIF` function as a sum of three different parameters, i always get a date **(like 00/jan)** as the result, not a natural number as i'd expect.

I've tried using the function `COUNTIFS` instead, only to achieve the same result.

The function i was trying to create is

```
=COUNTIF(B5:B23;"*criteria1*")+COUNTIF(B5:B23;"*criteria2*")+COUNTIF(B5:B23;"*criteria3*")
```

With COUNTIFS, it is as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS(B5:B23;"*criteria1*";B5:B23;"*criteria2*";B5:B23;"*criteria3*")
```

There is no error message, and all i want to get is a real number, that is, the real sum of those "criteria" appearing in the given interval.

Comment: Change the Format of the Cell to General in which you are applying the formula

Answer (score 0):

Excel tries to be helpful and takes a guess at the data type of the formula cell.

Unfortunately, Excel often gets it wrong. Especially when the formula processes dates, Excel will often format the cell as a date, too, even though the result may not be a date at all.

Your only option is to manually apply a different format to the cell. General or Number will show the real number.